# How to parse datetime with optional sections?

Tags: java, date, datetime, java-8, datetime-format

I've datetime that may be one of the following formats:

- MM/dd/yy
- M/dd/yy
- MM/d/yy
- M/d/yy
- Any of the above with HH:mm
- Any of the above with 4-digit year

The `DateTimeFormatter` I built is as follows:

```
new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendValue(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, 1, 2, SignStyle.NEVER)
    .appendLiteral('/')
    .appendValue(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1, 2, SignStyle.NEVER)
    .appendLiteral('/')
    .appendValue(ChronoField.YEAR_OF_ERA, 2, 4, SignStyle.NEVER)
    .optionalStart()
    .appendLiteral(' ')
    .appendValue(HOUR_OF_DAY, 2)
    .appendLiteral(':')
    .appendValue(MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 2)
    .toFormatter();
```

But it fails to format `2/9/17`. Why?

Comment: Parsing two-digit-years is something quite different than parsing normal years with varying width (2-4), compare `appendValueReduced(...)` versus your approach using `appendValue(YEAR_OF_ERA, 2, 4, ...)`.

Comment: @MenoHochschild Using `appendValueReduced(ChronoField.YEAR_OF_ERA, 2, 4, 2017)` gives an error "Text '2/9/17' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 2017-02-09 of type java.time.format.Parsed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendValue(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, 1, 2, SignStyle.NEVER)
    .appendLiteral('/')
    .appendValue(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1, 2, SignStyle.NEVER)
    .appendLiteral('/')
    .appendValueReduced(ChronoField.YEAR, 2, 4, yearMonth.getYear())
    .appendPattern("[ HH:mm]")
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 0)
    .toFormatter();
```

The error I posted in response to Meno Hochschild's comment is fixed by setting defaults for the optional hours and minutes.