# DateTime format both Zulu and Offset

Tags: java, datetime, formatting, datetime-format, datetime-parsing

I want to have one single date time pattern expression to be able to:

- Serialize date/instant with offset indicator, eg: **2017-07-13T21:20:33.123+0000**
- Parse string with zulu indicator, eg: **2017-07-13T21:20:33.123Z**
- Parse string with offset, eg: **2017-07-13T21:20:33.123+0200**

The important part is that the serialization always includes the offset (`+0000`)
And that the deserialization can handle both cases (`Z` or `+0000`)

**What I've tried so far:**

I'm using JDK8, with the new built-in `java.time` package. I've tried creating a `java.time.DateTimeFormatter` with the following patterns:

`yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXX` will work for parsing both `Z` and `+0000` but doesn't work when serializing. (It only outputs `Z` when using UTC for instance)

`yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ` does parse `+0000` but will not parse the `Z` if present

Is it possible to have one expression for this?

Fully testable code below:

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class DateTimeFormatterTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter
            .ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
            .withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
        final Instant now = Instant.now();

        System.out.println(dtf.format(now)); //THIS IS OK

        final String dateStringOffset = "2017-07-13T21:20:33.123+0200";
        System.out.println(dtf.parse(dateStringOffset)); //THIS IS OK

        final String dateStringZulu = "2017-07-13T21:20:33.123Z";
        System.out.println(dtf.parse(dateStringZulu)); //THIS IS NOT OK
    }
}
```

I was under the impression that appending `XX` to the end of the pattern would force it to always output offset in the format `+0000`

Comment: Well, have you tried anything yet? A [mcve] showing the test cases and problems you've encountered would be very helpful. Which date/time classes are you using? java.time? Joda Time? threeten-backpart? Old-school SimpleDateFormat? When you say "serialization always includes the offset" would you be okay with it using Z instead of +0000, but there should always be *something*?

Comment: @JonSkeet No that's the issue, it needs to be `+0000` and not the zulu-indicator. Added what I've tried so far

Comment: You haven't added what you've tried so far as a [mcve] that makes it easy for us to test changes though. You still haven't told us which libraries you're using. Please help us to help you...

Comment: Show some code, talk is cheap.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar code added

Comment: @JonSkeet Code added

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42310409/how-to-parse-datetime-with-optional-sections

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Never used DateTimeFormatterBuilder before, care to point in the right direction? What part is controlling the offset/zulu=?

Comment: @RobinJonsson It's never too late to start. If you **try** to use it, and have a problem, we're here to help. Believe me, Google and Javadoc are usually more helpful than people.

Comment: @RobinJonsson: If you've never used `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` before, then presumably you haven't tried that to solve your problem. Abhijit has suggested an option that you haven't tried - how is that "absolutely no help at all"?

Comment: (But thank you for including the mcve now. I'll investigate simple patterns...)

Comment: Do you absolutely *have* to have a single `DateTimeFormatter` for both parsing and formatting? If not, just use `xxxx` for formatting, and `XX` for parsing.

Comment: @JonSkeet Well I know it can be done with 2 different patterns, but the idea was to have one single pattern to rule them all! :)

Comment: At this point I suspect that while it may be *possible* with one pattern, it's likely to be significantly more complicated than using one pattern for parsing and one for formatting. (That's not as complicated as having to try two different patterns when parsing though...)

Comment: Just one little detail: instead of `ZoneId.of("UTC")`, you can use the constant `ZoneOffset.UTC` - from the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#of-java.lang.String-): *"If the zone ID equals 'GMT', 'UTC' or 'UT' then the result is a ZoneId with the same ID and rules equivalent to ZoneOffset.UTC"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

I've actually found a way, but it's not a pretty code (it uses reflection, which I personally prefer to not use, if possible).

## Details

I agree with the comments, that it's much easier to have 2 formatters (one for parsing and another for formatting).

Basically because it seems to have no way to do it with just one single formatter. I've tried with different combinations of optional patterns and the closest I've got was:

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS[xx][XX]").withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

This parses both offset and Zulu, but when formatting, the output ends with `+0000Z` (because the formatter always prints all the optional sections when formatting - it doesn't seem to have a way to change this behaviour).

The only way I could do it uses reflection. First I create a `ZoneId` and then I change the ID to an empty `String`, and the rules to match UTC (so it behaves like it was UTC). Then I use this modified zone in a formatter:

```
// get any zone, just to get a valid ZoneId
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Europe/London");
// change ID to empty string (so it's not printed by the formatter)
Field field = zone.getClass().getDeclaredField("id");
field.setAccessible(true);
field.set(zone, "");
// change zone rules to match UTC (so this zone becomes a "copy" of UTC)
field = zone.getClass().getDeclaredField("rules");
field.setAccessible(true);
field.set(zone, ZoneOffset.UTC.getRules());

DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // date and time
    .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")
    // optional offset - prints +0000 when it's zero (instead of Z)
    .optionalStart().appendOffset("+HHMM", "+0000").optionalEnd()
    // optional zone id (so it parses "Z")
    .optionalStart()
    .appendZoneId()
    // add default value for offset seconds when field is not present
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS, 0)
    .optionalEnd()
    // create formatter using the "UTC-cloned" zone
    .toFormatter().withZone(zone);

System.out.println(dtf.format(ZonedDateTime.now()));
System.out.println(dtf.format(Instant.now()));

String dateStringOffset = "2017-07-13T21:20:33.123+0200";
System.out.println(dtf.parse(dateStringOffset));

String dateStringZulu = "2017-07-13T21:20:33.123Z";
System.out.println(dtf.parse(dateStringZulu));
```

The output is:

> 2017-07-12T13:39:49.695+0000
> 2017-07-12T13:39:49.695+0000
> {OffsetSeconds=7200, InstantSeconds=1499980833},ISO, resolved to 2017-07-13T21:20:33.123
> {OffsetSeconds=0, InstantSeconds=1499980833},ISO,Z resolved to 2017-07-13T21:20:33.123

I had to add `parseDefaulting(ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS, 0)` because when a `Z` is found, the `OffsetSeconds` field wasn't set and the result couldn't be used to create a `OffsetDateTime`.

---

There are some problems with this formatter:

- the first of all is the use of reflection, of course. It's a matter of choice to use it in production environment (I personally avoid it), and it can throw a `SecurityException` if the `SecurityManager` is configured to not allow it (and [some other issues](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/101217/265778))
- the more subtle and tricky detail is that the parsed object prefers the `zone` instead of the offset.

So, in the first case (`dateStringOffset = 2017-07-13T21:20:33.123+0200`), if I try to create an `Instant` or a `ZonedDateTime`, it uses the local time `21:20:33` and the zone as UTC, ignoring the offset `+0200`:

```
dtf.parse(dateStringOffset, Instant::from); // Wrong: 2017-07-13T21:20:33.123Z
dtf.parse(dateStringOffset, ZonedDateTime::from); // Wrong: 2017-07-13T21:20:33.123Z[]
```

To get the correct result, I must use `OffsetDateTime`:

```
dtf.parse(dateStringOffset, OffsetDateTime::from); // Correct: 2017-07-13T21:20:33.123+02:00
```

For the second case, as it's in UTC (`Z`), all the three types work. But I recommend to always parse the result to an `OffsetDateTime`, and then convert it to other types.

---

Or keep it simple and just use 2 formatters:

```
// parse both offset and Z
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS[xx][XX]");
// format with offset (and +0000 instead of Z)
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSxx").withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

This doesn't have the side-effect above - it correctly parses the offset:

```
parser.parse(dateStringOffset, Instant::from); // 2017-07-13T19:20:33.123Z (Instant is always in UTC)
parser.parse(dateStringOffset, ZonedDateTime::from); // 2017-07-13T21:20:33.123+02:00
parser.parse(dateStringOffset, OffsetDateTime::from); // 2017-07-13T21:20:33.123+02:00
```

Comment: Wow! Excellent research! I too dislike using reflection. This was simply more of a question of "is it at all possible" and not a hard requirement :)
Really appriciate your answer!

Answer (score -1):

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .append(ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
    .appendPattern("[x][X]")
    .toFormatter();

System.out.println(formatter.parse("2017-07-13T21:20:33.123+0200")
    .get(ChronoField.YEAR)); // 2017
System.out.println(formatter.parse("2017-07-13T21:20:33.123Z")
    .get(ChronoField.YEAR)); // 2017
```

**Edit**:

Formatting can be done with the following:

`DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSxx")`

Comment: Formatting with that gives "+00Z" though :(

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: Year` when trying to format an `Instant` :(

Comment: @RobinJonsson `Instant` doesn't have a concept of year, it's a point in the linear timeline.

Comment: @JonSkeet I didn't check for formatting because he didn't ask.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar: No, the whole point of the question is that it can parse both +0000 and Z, but that it *formats* to +0000: "The important part is that the serialization always includes the offset (+0000)"

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't know how to make that happen. You can parse with options, but for formatting, you need to tell it what exactly to output.