# Parse LocalDateTime depending on input string

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

The client could be able to send either `String` in format
`"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"` or `"yyyy-MM-dd"` and depending on it I need to either just parse full `LocalDateTime` if he sent me full format or to create `LocalDateTime` object with default `Time` part `"23:59:59"`

For now I have written this solution but it seems to be bad as I am using exceptions for controlling business logic.

```
public class LocalDateTimeConverter implements IStringConverter<LocalDateTime> {

    private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime convert(String value) {
        LocalDateTime localDateTime;
        try {
            localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(value, DATE_TIME_FORMATTER);
        } catch (DateTimeParseException ex) {
            localDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.parse(value), LocalTime.of(23, 59, 59));
        }

        return localDateTime;
    }

}
```

Any suggestions about how to implement it more clearly?

Comment: Close duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42310409/how-to-parse-datetime-with-optional-sections but doens't answer the 'default time' part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've never worked with `parseDefaulting` but a quick shot at it seems to work.

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendValue(ChronoField.YEAR_OF_ERA, 4, 4, SignStyle.NEVER)
    .appendLiteral('-')
    .appendValue(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, 2, 2, SignStyle.NEVER)
    .appendLiteral('-')
    .appendValue(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 2, 2, SignStyle.NEVER)
    .optionalStart()
    .appendLiteral(' ')
    .appendValue(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 2)
    .appendLiteral(':')
    .appendValue(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 2)
    .appendLiteral(':')
    .appendValue(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 2)
    .optionalEnd()
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23)
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 59)
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 59)
    .toFormatter();

LocalDateTime.parse("2000-01-01 01:02:03", DATE_TIME_FORMATTER) // 2000-01-01T01:02:03
LocalDateTime.parse("2000-01-01", DATE_TIME_FORMATTER) // 2000-01-01T23:59:59
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the length of the input string to decide which format must be applied, like this:

```
public LocalDateTime convert(String value) {
    value = value.trim();
    boolean isShort = value.length() <= 10;
    DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER;

    if (isShort) {
        DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    } else {
        DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    }

    LocalDateTime localDateTime;
    try {
        localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(value, DATE_TIME_FORMATTER);
        if (isShort) {
            localDateTime = localDateTime.with(LocalTime.of(23, 59, 59));
        }
    } catch (DateTimeParseException ex) {
        localDateTime = null;
    }

    return localDateTime;
}
```